# How do I get the Facebook profile id using Android and Graph API?

Tags: android

How do I get a profile id of a Facebook profile to which I have logged in through my Android application?

I have been able to log in to Facebook using the Android and Graph API, but I want to fetch the profile ID of the specific Facebook profile to which I have logged in.

Please help me solve this problem. I am new to Android and the Facebook Graph API. I have searched a lot, but I didn't find any workaround to this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [Facebook graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) lets you make calls that return JSON, which you can parse in Android with a [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

```
Facebook fb = new Facebook(API_KEY);
// ... login user here ...
JSONObject me = new JSONObject(fb.request("me"));
String id = me.getString("id");
```

Comment: Hi ankit can you plz elaborate it with some more code of activity.

Comment: fb.request is now deprecated.  anyone know the new way?

Comment: @Ankit,I want an email id of user, I got it in some profile, I can't email ID for every profile, do you have any idea why this happen ?